# Raspberry Pi not sending instructions to a device via Serial Communication properly in Pyhton

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-communication

I am trying to write to a device via serial communication and the code is getting stuck on the `ser.write(b'U')` command. I am unsure as to whether I am able to send letters via serial communication in this manner.

I have attached my code here to show what I have written and it gets stuck on the line talking about the `ser.write(b'U')`, the code quits running and I have to hit CTRL+C to get anything to happen.

```
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS )
print (ser.name)
ser.write(b'U')
distance = 0

time.sleep(2)

ser.write(b'R')
distance = ser.read(100)
print (distance)

ser.close
```

I am looking to figure out why the code isnt running past that line and simply getting stuck.

Comment: Can you talk to the device over serial with the usual suspects - `screen`, `tip`, `cu`?

Comment: Do you use any program to simulate serial communicaton? If no, use that and then you can run your code. Otherwise the code will stop at the line related to serial read or write.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not familiar with those. Are you able to write those in a program  and change the inputs using that?

Comment: I meant for you to try and run one of them from the Terminal command-line (not within Python) just to check your baudrate, parameters and general connectivity.

Comment: On the device's datasheet all that type of information is given.

Comment: If we are trying to solve a problem, we need to rule out things until we find the solution. The datasheet can't check if your cables are crossed or broken, but running an external command-line program could immediately confirm your cables work and you have the right settings.